# auth0 do something after verification code is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, google-chrome-extension, auth0

Hello I am currently following this tutorial online:

https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/regular-web-app-email-code

and I have ran into a problem. Instead of being rediracted to a url when the code is correct I want to do something after like for example change the popup html file. Here is what I am using to verifiy the code. It works well I just want to be able to make it do stuff after the code is varified corect:

```
function login(){
  var email = $('#login-email').val();
  var code = $('#login-token').val();

  webAuth.passwordlessVerify({
    connection: 'email',
    email: email,
    verificationCode: code
  }, function (err,res) {
    if (err) {
      alert("Token invalid");
    } 
    //do this stuff if token is verified 
    alert("login successful");
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "popup.html"});
  });
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you <3!

Comment: Have you looked into [Promises and Callbacks](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)? They enable you to do asynchronous calls which is "do something when a request is done.".

Comment: I tried and It doesn't work @noogui

Comment: It is mentioned in the doc _If authentication is successful, the user will be redirected to the `redirectUri` specified in the Auth0 constructor._. You can modify the constructor as per your requirement.

Comment: @PallaviGoyal How would I modify the constructor???